# Using "parent::" or "self::" in call_user_func() in PHP 5.x

Tags: php, oop, methods, static, non-static

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

The "Changelog" section says:

> "The interpretation of object oriented keywords like parent and self has changed. Previously, calling them using the double colon syntax would emit an E_STRICT warning because they were interpreted as static."

1. This is calling a non-static method statically and this emits a warning ip PHP 5.x?
2. If so, how do we know that the method that we are calling is non-static? We are assuming that.
3. There is only two types of methods in this context - static and non-static, correct?

Comment: That has kind of always bothered me as well. To me, using `::` implies it must be a static method or variable. So, I tend to just enforce that *rule* in my own code by not confusing it. But in more complex objects... it gets dicey.

Comment: This is for `PHP5.3+`  I never seen the need for both `->` and `::`  Why cant we just rely on the definition of the method and use `Class->foo()` or `$Obj->bar()`,  it's a feature right.

Comment: It just says, that prior to 5.3 calling something like `parent::foo()` with `call_user_func()` would have raised a warning, because the scope resolution operator `::` was interpreted a static.

Comment: @code-kobold - It can be always assumed that the target method is non-static (why/how?)? And calling a non-static method statically generates a warning prior to php 5.3 (I mean, this is what this is about)?

Comment: Are you asking if this behavior was different in php 5.x; as opposed to php 7? In php < 5.3 in particular?

Comment: @yivi - I know that this does not apply to PHP 7. This can be seen as a "past time bug", but I want to have an understanding of this. I am learning the PHP.

Comment: Ok, but you are asking about 5.x, but I guess that you are specifically worried about php < 5.3, right?

Comment: @yivi - No, not at all. Any version that this pertains to. I just want to understand this text (and move on). I will be using the PHP 7 when I will start writing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call\_user\_func() - "parent::", "self::" - E\_STRICT warning - interpreted as static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576238/call-user-func-parent-self-e-strict-warning-interpreted-as-stat)